# How can I fix the power sliding doors on a Dodge Grand Caravan (VW Routan)?

Tags: door, grand-caravan

I have a 2011 Dodge Grand Caravan that came with power sliding doors.  But they don't work.  Is there a usual way they die?  It could be anything from the buttons to the wires to the sensors to the motor.  Is there a standard thing that should be replaced to get it working again?

Comment: I think this question has already been answered ... you might want to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

The most common point of failure on these minivans is the wiring harness in the bottom sliding door track. It breaks where it is being flexed back and forth every time the door opens. Look for a plastic "tank tread" in the bottom rear. It will contain the harness that you need. See Dorman 747-311 and 747-310